Break a link to an external reference in Excel Using Apache POI
Is it feasible to remove workbook links (external references) using Apache POI in Java? I understand that Excel provides a way to break links to external workbooks manually, but is there a way to programmatically identify and remove external links (formulas or named ranges referencing other workbooks) using Apache POI?
public static void breakExternalLinks(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws IOException {
        // Load the Excel workbook
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        // Break external links in formulas by replacing them with their current values
        breakFormulaLinks(workbook);

        // Remove external references in named ranges
        removeExternalNamedRanges(workbook);

        // Save the updated workbook
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
        workbook.write(fos);

        // Close resources
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
        workbook.close();
    }

private static void breakFormulaLinks(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        evaluator.setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks(true); // Ignore missing external workbooks

        for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                        try {
                            // Evaluate the formula and replace it with the calculated value
                            CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
                            switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
                                case BOOLEAN:
                                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
                                    break;
                                case NUMERIC:
                                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue.getNumberValue());
                                    break;
                                case STRING:
                                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue.getStringValue());
                                    break;
                                case ERROR:
                                    cell.setCellErrorValue(cellValue.getErrorValue());
                                    break;
                                case BLANK:
                                    cell.setBlank();
                                    break;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Error evaluating formula in cell " + cell.getAddress() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void removeExternalNamedRanges(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        // Collect all named ranges with external references
        List<XSSFName> namesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        // Iterate over all named ranges in the workbook
        for (XSSFName name : workbook.getAllNames()) {
            // Check if the name refers to an external workbook (contains a [ symbol)
            if (name.getRefersToFormula() != null && name.getRefersToFormula().contains("[")) {
                namesToRemove.add(name);
            }
        }

        // Remove all external references from named ranges
        for (XSSFName name : namesToRemove) {
            workbook.removeName(name);
        }
    }


Here the images attached for facing issue

You don't need to break links. The cells contain a cached value which you can use instead of evaluating the formula.

I am trying to achieve mentioned in the below reference
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/break-a-link-to-an-external-reference-in-excel-f1ca8b08-4f24-4af6-92e5-f4fdb1442748#:~:text=On%20the%20Data%20tab%2C%20in,that%20you%20want%20to%20break.)
using apache poi lib, it is not worked with apache poi. It is limitation of the Apache POI. Can you verify and let me know @M.Deinum

But you don't need to. You can just get the cached value instead. Why do you need to break the link? What is the usecase?

Hi @M.Deinum
Could you please take a look at the attached screenshots regarding the issue I'm facing with external references in Excel files? I am using Apache POI to handle these files, and I need guidance on how to resolve this issue effectively.
article:
link
Could you let me know if it's possible to manage this operation using Apache POI?

What have the screenshots to do with Apache POI? I don't get your reasoning. YOu don't have a link but still try to evaluate the formula in code, how would you think that would work. As stated just get the cached value. However it still beats me why you want to remove the link if you are processing them with Apache POI in the first place.
